# COUNTA and FILTER returning a 1 when it should return a 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I am using a summary page to show stats from a registration page. I want to show the number of registrations based on their date of registration (which is in column A of the Registrations page.
I modified a formula offered here via a different post:

```
=countA(FILTER('Reg-6-20-2019'!A$2:A,LEFT('Reg-6-20-2019'!A$2:A,2)="01"))
```

So this should return all of the registrations that were made in "01" because the exported format from the software is in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format. It does this fine.
I add cells to display 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08
All of them work great, but when I get to 07 and 08 (future registrations) which should return 0, it returns a 1.

Not a big deal, but not sure I understand why it would do this. All months that actually have registrations are correct.

It does correctly output a 1 for July if I put an July entry into the data sheet, and a 2 if I put in 2 of them, but why am I getting a 1 if there are no such entries matching the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

It's because if there are no entries, then **`FILTER`** can't fetch data eg. **`FILTER`** will output **`#N/A`** error and **`COUNTA`** doesn't care and counts **`#N/A`** as **`1`**. Therefore try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER('Reg-6-20-2019'!A$2:A, LEFT('Reg-6-20-2019'!A$2:A, 2)="01")))
```

Comment: @MainelyTom please read: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers